# Primer cracked or showing spider web micro cracks-what is the proper way to fix this?

Tags: primer

I don't have a lots of places just two spots, one is bad ...shown in the pictures below; first is on the ceiling, secon is on the wall; both sections painted before
The other one has small cracks visible if you look close, both for around 2"x 4" areas

This is two days after priming, I wonder if this could extend to other areas. The above showed up like within 2h after I did the work. Nothing else seem to be wrong for the room

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like bad paint bonding to the surface.  About the only fix is a re-do.  Sand/scrape all loose paint off, make sure surface is clean and dry, and repaint.

Comment: you mean primer bonding not paint bonding
I wonder what might have caused this because there was the same prep work done everywhere but only these spots were affected. I suspect it was applying too much primer on that particular area

Comment: Can you briefly describe what kind of surface prep you did before applying the new primer?

Comment: Two of my walls were painted but one of them  needed some straightening and patching holes were a fixture used to be. None of these fixes are near the affected areas. So it was sanding and then removing the dust. The ceiling strip showed in the first picture was painted before but not touched for sanding or anything else. The second picture is on the same horizontal strip near a corner so maybe that is the common thing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK this is confirmed
The areas where this happened were in fact patched (the painted wall had problems and I applied some mud there) and it seems that the area was still too humid to apply primer there. I realized this by repeating the mistake... I did use a hair dryer (I did not have Sheetrock 45 or similar) to dry up regular mud and in some patches (thiner patches) it worked but others although they looked dry and I could sand it seems that deeper they still had humidity and that caused the cracking later